# Windows Sharing requires password

Tags: windows, networking, network-share

I have 3 machines on my local network

Machine A , Machine B and Machine C

OS on all machines is : Windows 7 64bit.

Sharing Permissions on all machines : Everyone ( Read/Write ) no domain.

Sharing folder name : project

> Machine A is sharing folder over the network without password.
>
> Machine B is sharing folder over the network without password.
>
> Machine C is sharing folder over the network without password.

**Machine A** can normally access **B** and **C** without password required.

**Machine B** can normally access **A** and **C** without password required

**Machine C** can normally access **`Machine B`** without password. **My problem is** **`Machine C`** requires a password when it access **`Machine A`** also the shared folder in **`Machine A`** don't have password protected and **`Machine B`** can access **`Machine A`** without a password !

How can i solve the problem .?

Comment: Tell us more please. Share names, share permissions, users involved, Domain, no Domain,...

Comment: @MichelZ  Sharing Permissions on all machines : Everyone ( Read/Write ) no domain.

Sharing folder name : project

Comment: Is there any entry in the Security event log with the name of the user - maybe a "logon failed" message or something like that?

Comment: Also, you said you granted "Everyone" access. Is it safe to assume you have not granted "Anonymous Logon" access?